# javascript all possible arrangements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have an array of (in my case it will be digits only, but I don't think that's very relevant) integers and I wanna get an array of all possible arrangements of this array so let's say

```
    arr = [1,4,5]
allArrangements(arr) 
// [[1,4,5],[1,5,4],[4,1,5],[4,5,1],[5,1,4],[5,4,1]]
```

Comment: Ok so.... what did you try?

Comment: Give it a go. If you run into a **specific** problem doing this yourself, after doing thorough research and [searching SO](/help/searching), if you cannot resolve the problem, post your code and a description of the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You have to multiply the total of items from highest to lowest

- `[1,4,5]` > `3*2*1` = 6 possible arrangements
- `[1,4,5,6]` > `4*3*2*1` = 24 possible arrangements
- `[1,4,5,6,7]` > `5*4*3*2*1` = 120 possible arrangements

```js
var array = [1,4,5,6];
function permutation (arr){
  var len = arr.length,
      i = len-1,
      ags = len;
  while(i--){
    len--;
    ags *= len;
  }
  return ags;
}
console.log(permutation(array));
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for the permutations themselves, not the number of permutations.